# View doesn't want to re-render after store dispatch is called in Redux (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I need to change text input value after the state in redux has been changed (re-render the view). That means everything from text input will be stored in redux store (after each character) and re-rendered back to the input. If I use setState without redux, the view is changed successfully but also if I use `this.forceUpdate()` method for force re-render in `handleChange` function.

I think that's problem of the fact, that state in reducer isn't changed properly. I googled many way to do it but nothing doesn't worked for me.

Reduced code here:

```
'use strict';

import * as React from "react";
import { createStore } from 'redux';

interface State
{

}

interface Props
{

}

function cardReducer(state = {redirect : false, cardId : ""}, action) {
    console.log("reducer action: " + JSON.stringify(action));
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TYPING':
            return  Object.assign({}, state, {
                redirect : false,
                cardId : action.cardId
            });            

        default:
            return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(cardReducer);
console.log("STORE state: " + JSON.stringify(store.getState()));

export class Home extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props : any)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        store.dispatch({ type : 'TYPING', cardId : store.getState().cardId + e.target.value});

    };



    render()
    {                
         return (
                <div className={"container cardwrapper offset-md-2 col-md-8"}>
                    <form>
                        <input value={store.getState().cardId} onChange={this.handleChange} id={"card_id"} className={"command"} type="text" autoFocus autoComplete={"off"}/>
                    </form>
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `connect` and `mapStateToProps` (Google these two). Doing `store.getState()` in the component is not how React listens for updates.

Comment: he is not using the react-redux library, and those helper methods are supplied by that library

Comment: Well, yes, but he should.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the data from store.getState(), you need to set it on your state as well for your component to be re rendered.

You can do it as follows:

1. Put cardId on your state inside the constructor as follows:

   this.state {
       cardId: ""
   }
2. Then on getting update from store, set the state as:

   this.setState({
       cardId: store.getState().cardId;
   });